# Python functions that return Matplotlib axes--how do you combine them all in one figure?

Tags: matplotlib

Let's say that I made functions that return an axes object.  For example, say a plot of a sine and cosine function.

```
def func1():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    return ax

def func2():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))
    return ax
```

These functions return, of course, the following plots:

[image]
[image]

How can I combine the two into one figure which would be equivalent to the following code and image?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xs = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

That is to say, could I do something like the pseudocode below?

```
ax1 = func1()
ax2 = func2()

fig = plt.figure()
fig.append_axes(ax1)
fig.append_axes(ax2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What prevents you from returning `x` and `y` instead of `ax`? It will make things much simpler.

Comment: You know, it's funny, but you're right.  This is one of those "can't see the forest for the trees" kind of things...

Comment: I have half a mind to delete this, but I suppose I'll leave up in case anyone else out there finds themselves searching for an answer for longer than they care to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
def func1():
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def func2():
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    plt.plot(x, np.cos(x))


func1()
func2()
```

output:
[image]